# Special commands for absolute value and norm

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

Normally in LaTeX I find it very annoying to read and edit paired delimiters such as `\lvert x \rvert`, so I would `\usepackage{physics}` that provides `\abs` and `\norm` or write my own such as with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}`, so I can write the much nicer `\abs{x}` and `\norm{x}`. The only way I've found to get this to work with MathJax is by inserting  `\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}` [somewhere in math mode](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros.html). Can special macros be defined globally for these commonly used delimiters?

(While we're at it, add `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}` and `\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}` for probability use.)

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19145/471884.

Comment: if you have some program that can do text-replacement when you type a keyword (this is a built in feature of Mac OS) / or a permanent clipboard (there exist commercial solutions), you can prepare a preamble that should be somewhat convenient to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible as the `physics` package is not supported; `\newcommand` (or `\def`) is the best there is. See [$\rm\TeX$ Commands available in MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm).

Note there are alternatives like `\left| \right|` and `\left\| \right\|` for absolute value and norm respectively. In general, I'd normally avoid declaring an operator using only one character.